# Improper Integral Fourier .1

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Hi guys I'm looking to evaluate the following integral. Would someone be able to help me? I'm desperate, it is for an exam.

The integral I have to evaluate is as follows:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\omega|\hat{G}(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega $$

where the function G(x) is :
$$
G(x) =
\begin{cases}
2-\frac{2x^2}{\pi^2} &  -\pi<x \leq0 
\\ cosx+1 & 0<x \leq \pi
\end{cases} 
$$
I am aware that the integral vanishes.

Thanks all.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! We are not here to blindly answer questions, especially when you state that it is for an exam. We expect to see you put in some effort and show us where you are stuck so we can help you understand the process

Comment: I do not want the exercise to be solved, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: I think that the exercise to solve with Plancherel's theorem but there is an omega before of module and i think that is the derivative but i'm not sure